# MvvmCross: Get this error after upgrade to Monotouch version 3.2.1

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

After I upgrade Xamarin to the latest version 3.2.1. I got the following error when I build my project? Anyone know why? and How to fix it?

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.1/lib/mono/4.0/Microsoft.CSharp.Targets (CoreCompile target) ->

ViewModels/UserInfoViewModel.cs(101,17): error CS0012: The type `System.Windows.Input.ICommand' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. Consider adding a reference to assembly`System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Its a known problem. Since release of Mono 3.2.0 the PCL was broken.
http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/6344/mono-3-2-0-update-breaks-pcl-support#latest

Fortunately it has been fixed in the most recent release i.e. Mono 3.2.2.
If you are on Alpha release, I suggest you update to Mono 3.2.2 and it should work.
If you can not update, you can trick Xamarin Studio to use Mono 3.1.2 runtime where PCL worked fine. You can find more details here. http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/21917/#Comment_21917

Comment: Actually, version 3.2.1 is working for me on PCL supports. I have to replace my MvvmCross binary to use the Mac Version instead of Windows to resolve my issue.